# What is the websocket timeout when the internet connection is suddenly interrupted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, tcp

I have a simple websocket from a web browser to a backend (node.js and [ws package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)).

When the network connection of the websocket is suddenly broken, the websocket remains open and allows to send further messages. There is no built-in mechanism to detect sudden network problems. This can easily be handled by implementing a [ping/pong mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24606380/1073393) - a `ping` is sent periodically and if the second party does not respond with `pong`, the connection is marked as lost. But my question is about a websocket without this ping/pong mechanism.

What happens to messages that are sent to such a zombie socket that appears to be connected but was suddenly disconnected? I have not found any answer explaining the behaviour of such a zombie socket. Based on my experiments:

- The messages are stored somewhere (or looping in the network). If the client reconnects before  timeout, all the messages are correctly delivered to the client at once.
- After the timeout (16 minutes for my set up), the server recognises the client as disconnected and the messages are never delivered.

Where are the messages stored before the client is reconnected? How is the timeout (16 minutes) determined?

Comment: The messages get lost. there is no backpressure mechanism.

Comment: No exactly. During my experiments, messages were not lost in the first 16 minutes.

Comment: Note: my messages were always sent from the node.js backend to client (tested both browser client and node.js client, same behaviour).

Comment: Didnt know that works, what happens when the client "connect" again, does this trigger a new "connection" event on the server side ? or can you reuse the existing (dead?) socket ?

Comment: When reconnecting in the first 16 minutes the old socket is reused, all waiting messages all delivered to the client in the correct order and I can use the old connection to send further messages. After 16 minutes the old connection is closed forever.